# My PHP UPDATE query is only working on the first item.

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and i'm having the following question:

I'm getting the supply table by the query SELECT * FROM Supply

I want to have a add and a subtract button to add or distract a amount to the supply.

When I want to add to the second product, it does not work, only the first product shown can change the amount to the database.

So if I'm having a coca cola, pie and ducktape. I can't add more amounts of pie or ducktape, only coca cola works, it doesn't show the name of pie and ducktape either..

What's wrong with my code?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "name", "password", "test");
   if(mysqli_connect_errno())
   { echo "Failed to connect to MYSQL:" . mysqli_connect_error();}
   $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM supply");

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

   echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" value=".$row['productname']."><br>";
   echo $row['description']."<br>";
   echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"amount\" value=".$row['amount']."></br>";
   echo "<form action=\"page2.php\" method=\"get\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"add\" value=\"+\"></input></form></br>";
   ?>
   <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php $amountl ?>"></input><?}?>
```

Second page:

```
<?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","name","password","test");
 $aantal = $_POST['amount'] + 1;
 $naam = $_POST['name'];
 $sql = ( "UPDATE  `test`.`supply` SET  `amount` =  '$amount' WHERE  `supply`.`productname` =  '$name' ");
 mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ('Error');
 echo "amount = ".$amount. "</br> <a href=\"supply.php\"> click</a>";
 echo "name= ".$name."</br>";?>
```

Comment: you have used `$naam` instead of `$name`.. try replacing it first..

Comment: Sorry, I translated  the code to english for this site, naam is dutch for name

Comment: ya I got it.. But in 3rd line you have written `$naam` and in 7th you have written `$name`

Comment: and yes please use a `primary key` to update the amount.. Put a `primary key` in your table.. 
so your query will be..

`$sql = ( "UPDATE  test.supply SET  amount =  $amount WHERE  supply.id =  '$id' ");`

get this ID from a `hidden field` from your post form...